# $routeParams Hard Refresh not working on server (base tag needed)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, .htaccess

Here is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html [NC,L]
```

Here is app.js

```
var app = angular.module('router', ['ngRoute']);

app.controller('main', function($scope, $location, $routeParams){
    $scope.test = 'testing';
    $scope.theID = $routeParams.theID;
});

// Routing Configuration
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/about', {
            templateUrl: 'views/about.html'
        })
        .when('/paramtest/:theID', {
            templateUrl: 'views/aboutID.html',
            controller: 'main'
        })
        .otherwise({
            templateUrl: 'views/home.html'
        });

        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);
```

Here is aboutID.html

```
ID: {{theID}}
```

When I go to `http://example.com/about` it works great, even if I do a cmd+r refresh it still loads the page fine.

If I click on a link from within the app and go to `http://example.com/paramtest/1234` it works fine.

The problem is if I try going directly to `http://example.com/paramtest/1234` or doing a hard refresh `http://example.com/paramtest/1234` angular routing no longer works and all of the variables are outputted like this `{{var}}`

I also have the `<base href="/">` tag in place.

-- ADDITONAL FILES --

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Contractors</title>

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="styles/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="styles/classic.date.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/4.0.1/dropzone.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="js/ng-sortable.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="js/jquery.fancybox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.2/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/1.0.0/angularfire.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.13/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.13/angular-animate.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-datepicker.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>

<base href="/">

</head>

<body ng-app="bidder" ng-controller="main" flow-drag-enter="style={border: '5px solid green'}">
    <div class="header" ng-controller="main">
        <div class="logo">
            <a href="/"><img src="images/logo.png"></a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- MAIN CONTENT -->
    <div ng-view ng-controller="main" class="view-animate" ng-if="firebaseUser"></div>

    <div class="profileSection" ng-if="firebaseUser" ng-controller="main">
        <div class="profileTopLeft">
            <img src="thumb.php?w=30&h=30&src=uploads/{{user.profilePicture || noPicture.png}}" ng-if="user.profilePicture" class="profilePicTop"> 
            <i class="fa fa-user" ng-if="!user.profilePicture"></i> 
            <b>{{user.Name}}</b> <small>{{user.Email}}</small>
        </div>
        <div class="profileTopRight">
            <a href="profile"><i class="fa fa-th-list"></i> My Profile</a>
            <a href ng-click="logoutUser()"><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i> Logout</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- REGISTRATION -->
    <div ng-if="!firebaseUser" ng-controller="main">
        <loginregister></loginregister>
    </div>

    <div class="clear" style="height: 100px;"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.expander.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/4.0.1/dropzone.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Routing segment from app.js

```
// PAGE SETUP
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/about', {
            templateUrl: 'views/about.html'
        })
        .when('/findcontractor', {
            templateUrl: 'views/findcontractor.html'
        })
        .when('/editjob/:jobID', {
            templateUrl: 'views/editjob.html'
        })
        .when('/viewcandidates/:jobID/:validate', {
            templateUrl: 'views/viewcandidates.html'
        })
        .when('/messenger/:creatorID/:jobID/:candidateID', {
            templateUrl: 'views/messenger.html'
        })
        .when('/profile', {
            templateUrl: 'views/profile.html'
        })
        .when('/findwork', {
            templateUrl: 'views/findwork.html'
        })
        .otherwise({
            templateUrl: 'views/home.html'
        });

        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);
```

Normal url's like `http://example.com/about/` work perfectly, but any parameter pages don't work on a hard refresh, it either returns 404 or index.html without any javascript included.

Comment: what errors are thrown? Do you have a `<base>` tag?

Comment: are you getting a 404 error?

Comment: Yes I have a base tag, no i'm not getting a 404 error, none of the variables in Angular display, i'm not getting any error messages but it looks like scope is completely gone.

Comment: Can you share the  index.html code?

Comment: is this state is nested or I mean to say child state ?  Which you are hard refreshing.

Comment: I'm hard refreshing any state with parameters, any state with parameters isn't working: (ex. http://domain.com/job/1234)

Comment: @manasisakhare Just included it in the question.

Comment: I would put `<base>` tag right *after* `<title>` tag. Maybe that's why you have a problem, mixing absolute/relative paths with your resources (think base is not applied on resources before it)

Comment: @JustinIurman That was it! That solved the problem.

Comment: @Jordash Glad your problem is solved

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If anyone runs into a similar problem to this one, make sure that you put your

`<base href="/">`

At the top of your index.html file, directly underneath the title.

That's what eventually solved it for me.

Answer (score 2):

Ok. In your index.html I see that there are multiple nested html elements with same controller. If you have applied the `ng-controller="main"` to your `<body>` tag then its not needed to add it again to its nested elements (child elements of body tag). Due to this nested scope of one single controller, it may cause the problems which you face.

Just add the controller to your body tag alone, or add a parent div which contains all that body contains, and then assign the controller to this parent div. And remove the redundant controller from other places.