# AngularJS routes + .htacces rewriting + route Parameters = not working

Tags: angularjs, .htaccess, routes, url-parameters

This essentially is a repost of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30009182/universal-htaccess-for-angularjs-that-works-with-html5-route-parameters?newreg=0c51e12e7f2b45dd8a4da5ef158889ae) Since the question wasn't correctly answered.

Using a basic set of self explainatory htaccess rewrites

```
RewriteEngine on

    # Don't rewrite files or directories
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    # Rewrite everything else to index.html to allow html5 state links
    RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
```

Consider the following links.

```
1. http://localhost/clouds
2. http://localhost/wind
3. http://localhost/city/Tokyo
```

Links 1 and 2 are working fine upon page refresh but link 3 is only accessible through page navigation (clicking the link). If I manually pase the third link in the browser I get to the Index page, unlike link 1 and 2.

My route config:

```
theApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    "use strict";
    console.log('Configuring');
    $routeProvider.when('/clouds', {
        templateUrl: 'Views/Cloud.html',
        controller: 'cloudController'

    }).when('/wind', {
        templateUrl: 'Views/Wind.html',
        controller: 'windController'

    }).when('/city/:cityName', {
        templateUrl: 'Views/City.html',
        controller: 'cityController'

    });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);
```

P.S. I did put . If i hadn't link 1 and 2 wouldn't be working.

EDIT: My bad I did not add the anchor tags leading to these links.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#"> Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/clouds"> Cloud</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/wind"> Wind</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/city/Tokyo"> CHAT!!!</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to place the `<base href="/" />` At the very top of the  tag.
It works, although I would like to know HOW AND WHY!!

Credits: [This stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30063399/5080520)